# $\lim_{n\to\infty} ((n+1)^x-n^x)$ for $x>0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I was asked to calculate  $\lim_{n\to\infty} ((n+1)^x-n^x)$ for $x>0$.
I think that I should solve this according to the value of $x$. For $ x\in\mathbb N $ and $x\ne1$ : I found that $\lim_{n\to\infty} ((n+1)^x-n^x)=\infty$.
For $ x=1$ : I found that $\lim_{n\to\infty} ((n+1)^x-n^x)=1$.
I did not figure out what to do regarding the other possibilities.
I appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$x,y>0$;

MVT:

$\dfrac{(y+1)^x-y^x}{1}= xz^{x-1}$, $z \in (y,y+1)$;

Note: $y \rightarrow \infty$ implies $z \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 0):

To make things simple, suppose that $x$ is a positive whole number.

For $x=1$, the problem is simple.

If  $x >1$, apply the binomial expansion. The term in $n^x$ will disappear and you are left with a polynomial of degree $(n-1)$. So the limit is $\infty$.

Now, suppose that $x$ is the reciprocal of a positive whole number. Using the binomial expansion or equivalents or Taylor series, you will show that
$$(n+1)^x-n^x\sim x n^{x-1}$$ and then the limit is $0$.